Firebase crashlytics also collects e.printStackTrace() automatically?
I saw some crashes but one of them was kind of vague. 
I found the point which occurred the crash and i used e.printStackTrace() there. 
So, I thought Firebase crashlytics collects also e.printStackTrace() error log. 
Am i right? 
Thank you in advance! :)
the code
try {
   // crash happens here!
} catch (e: Exception) {
  e.printStackTrace()
}


No. The code e.printStackTrace() just prints the exception stack trace to the system log.  Crashlytics doesn't read the log directly (and it can't on Android due to the permission system).
